# eclipse: "Clean Up" only a section of the code

Tags: eclipse, format, refactoring, code-formatting, code-cleanup

In Eclipse, you can use `Source > Format` and `Source > Clean Up...` to format and clean up the current source file. However, `Format` has the additional feature. You can select some lines, then click `Source > Format`, and only the selected lines will be formatted.

`Clean Up` doesn't have this feature. Selecting lines before clicking `Source > Clean Up...` has no effect. The whole file is still formatted.

Is there a way to enable this functionality for `Clean Up`? probably not, and if so, are there any third-party plugins that offer this kind of selective code cleanup (according to the rules specified by `Clean Up`)?

Comment: In the _Clean up_ dialog you can click _Next_ and then select which changes should be performed and which not in this file.

Comment: @howlger yes, but this still applies the chosen profile to the full file. i'm looking to clean up only a section of the file

Comment: If you click _Next_ you will get to the preview page with a tree with check boxes at the top. Clear the root check box and then tick one or more individual changes you want to apply to the file.

Comment: @howlger the problem I'm having is not the fineness of the control of what cleanup actions are performed. I want to apply ALL my selected cleanup actions, but ONLY to the selected section of code. for example, if my cleanup includes "Add missing '@Override' annotations", and I'm in a file with two functions without the annotations, I want it that if I highlight lines containing only one of these functions, ONLY that function is corrected. the un-highlighted function remains untouched (in fact, the rest of the file remains untouched. only the selected section of the file is modified).

Comment: Sure, except that it works differently as you describe, without selecting anything in the Java editor first, but selecting the parts (e.g. a single method of a class) at the end. If you want it to work your way, write a plugin or contribute a patch to Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger on the screen you describe, i only see a single checkbox. unchecking it doesn't give me any options to apply cleanup to only a selection of the file. can you show a screenshot of what you're talking about? 

> "If you want it to work your way...". i know it doesn't work that way. that's why i said in the post that i was looking to see if there were any plugins that had this functionality.

Comment: Left of the checkbox there is a handle to expand the subtree.

Comment: @howlger no handle appears. i'm on the newest version of eclipse. could you show a screenshot, showing what appears when you expand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228548/discussion-between-starwarswii-and-howlger).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99CL7.png And what do you see?

Comment: To answer the question you asked me in the chat: enhancements and bugs can be reported to Eclipse (in this case _Eclipse Project > JDT_) here: https://bugs.eclipse.org (see e.g. [this new clean-up idea which has already been implemented](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571040)).

Comment: @howlger this is really strange. https://i.imgur.com/hWhlCe5.png why does it let me fine-tune the cleanup for one file and not the other? TestUtils has a variety of different fixups just like CleanupTestEnv does. is this a bug?